# Declaring Anonymous Inner class

Tags: java

```
rb.addActionListener(new ActionEvent(ae) {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
     nowCall(ae);
    }
});
```

**Another way**

```
Thread th=new Thread(Runnable r) {
  public void run() {
    // do something
  }
};

// notice the ending of above 2 snippets
```

I am really confused seeing these two.It seems there is no exact pattern to declare an anonymous inner class.

*please explain the syntax for anonymous inner class.*

Comment: Classes are anonymous OR inner. You have examples of anonymous classes. An inner class is a non-static nested classes which has a name.

Comment: @Peter Oracle disagrees with you. See [Local and Anonymous Inner Classes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html)

Answer (score 8):

The second isn't valid, as far as I can see and test.

What would be more common would be to create a new Runnable implementation:

```
Thread th=new Thread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    // This implements Runnable.run
  }
});
```

Now you *could* just override the `run` method of a normal thread:

```
Thread th=new Thread() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    // This overrides Thread.run
  }
};
```

... but personally I prefer specifying the `Runnable` separately when creating a thread.

Now the difference that you noticed at the end is simply whether the expression is used as an argument (e.g. to the `addActionListener` method or the `Thread(Runnable)` constructor, or whether it's just assigned directly to the variable. Think of the whole `new TypeName() { ... }` as a single expression, and it's just the difference between:

```
Thread th = expression;
```

and

```
Thread th = new Runnable(expression);
```

Comment: @ Jon Skeet
in your first snippet runnable interface is implemented in run?

Comment: @Meprogrammer: Yes, that's the only method in Runnable.

Comment: @ Jon Skeet Of all constructors [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html),which constructor of thread is being used in your first example.?

Comment: @Meprogrammer: The second one, which has a single parameter of type `Runnable`.

Comment: @ Jon Skeet I can't understand 'how' .Can you explain

Comment: @ Jon Skeet what i understand of second constructor is "Argument will accept the 'instance' of class that has implemented Runnable." If true can you give a relation with your piece

Answer (score 2):

There is the difference that in the first case your passing it as an parameter to a method and in the second example you're storing it in a local variable.

So you can't really compare both examples against each other.

Comment: You can't just "directly override" a method. Both are anonymous inner classes, in fact there's no difference at all in their declaration.

Comment: both are anon. there ain't a difference.

Comment: Sure it's an anonymous class. Could *you* tell the name of this particular subclass of Thread?

Comment: Ok I see. I change the answer.

Answer (score 2):

> [...] **notice the ending of above 2 snippets**

The trailing `)` in your first example is simply a termination of

```
rb.addActionListener(
```

(i.e., your two examples have different endings because one is a right hand side of an assignment

> `Thread th = ...`  **`;`**

and the other is an argument to a method call

> `...addActionListener( ...` **`);`**

The syntax of creating an anonymous class is simply:

```
new SomeClassOrInterface() {
    // implementation goes here
}
```

Which as you can see is the pattern for both of your examples.

---

From [Anonymous Classes (Java in a Nutshell)](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm):

> **3.12.3. New Syntax for Anonymous Classes**
>
> We've already seen examples of the syntax for defining and instantiating an anonymous class. We can express that syntax more formally as:
>
> ```
> new class-name ( [ argument-list ] ) { class-body }
> ```
>
> or:
>
> ```
> new interface-name () { class-body }
> ```

---

Also, you have a typo in your second example. It should probably read `new Thread() { ...` or `new Thread(r) { ...` (though in the latter case the overridden method will not be called).

Answer (score 0):

1. Instanciating new anonymous class and passing the object to `addActionListener` method.
2. Instanciating new anonymous class and assigning the object to local variable `th`

Answer (score 0):

They are both the same. You put the anonymous class right after the declaration, before the semicolons:
`new ActionEvent(ae)` `{class details, methods etc}` `;`

and

`Thread(Runnable r)` `{ public void run() {  // do something }}` `;`

in both cases you create a new instance of the class, in the first example you use it as a parameter to method, and in the second you assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that you can either implement an interface as an anonymous inner class or extend a class. In you example both are extending a class