# Live method overrride

Tags: java, code-snippets

I'm pretty new to Java and I'm finishing my first project using it. Basically I read Head First Java and the API documentation for the classes I've used so far. That's my Java background.

This little piece of code rose a big little doubt on me, basically, what does this statement mean?

```
DataSource dataSource = new FileDataSource(tiffFile) {
    public String getContentType() {
        return "image/tiff";
    }
};
```

Is it like a "live method override"? I still don't get what those brackets are doing there.

I'd really appreciate your help on this one.

Cheers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Declaring Anonymous Inner class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511864/declaring-anonymous-inner-class)

Comment: @Thilo Disagree. The linked question is asking for clarification on the syntax. This question is simply asking what a given piece of syntax is. How was the OP here supposed to locate that other question if they didn't know what an anonymous inner class was yet?

Comment: actually you're right, this is a duplicate. I just didn't know the name for the concept represented by that code snippet. Please close it if necessary. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've run across is an Anonymous Inner Class. There are many kinds of nested classes in Java and it would be beneficial for you to be familiar with all of them. I am including a link to a tutorial as a good starting point. Good luck!

[Nested Classes in Java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Answer (score 2):

It's called an Anonymous Inner Class. This creates a subclass of a `FileDataSource` with a call to the super contructor `FileDataSource(tiffFile)`, in which the `getContentType()` method becomes overriden.

It can be rewritten as follows:

```
public static class TiffFileSource extends FileDataSource {
    public TiffFileSource(File file){
        super(file);
    }
    public String getContentType() {
        return "image/tiff";
    }
}

DataSource dataSource = new TiffFileSource(tiffFile);
```